# How to transform Flow<T> to StateFlow<List<T>> in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

There is a Flow like this

```kotlin
val flow = flow {
    for (i in 1..100) {
      emit(i)
    }
  }
```

I need to display all the element in this flow to the screen, so I need to convert `Flow<Int>` to `StateFlow<List<Int>>`.

what should i do?

> Note: Do not modify the code inside `flow`, similar to `emit(list)`

### first edit

I need to use `StateFlow<T>.collectAsStateWithLifecycle` to display data on Screen.

If i use `flowOf((1..100).toList())`, then I need two `Flow`, which is of course a solution. But what I am looking for is to directly convert `Flow<Int>` to `StateFlow<List<Int>>`.

Comment: StateFlow is not appropriate for displaying all the elements in the flow to the screen.  And why are you emitting the range if you ultimately want a list? Why not use `flowOf((1..100).toList())`? If you only have one list to show, why use a Flow at all? Please be more precise about what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Tenfour04 StateFlow is not appropriate for displaying all the elements in the flow to the screen. Why do you say that? If I want to return data to the screen from the coroutine, only use StateFlow. I added the content of the question.

Comment: Oh, I meant to delete that sentence after I realized you want to display a whole list at once. I was thrown off by how you're creating the source flow. If you want a flow of a single item (which is a code smell) you could do `MutablestateFlow((1..100).toList()).asStateFlow()`. Usually a flow of any kind is for when you have a stream of values. "If I want to return data to the screen from the coroutine, only use StateFlow." Why do you say this? There are many ways to get data to the screen. If you're using Compose, you ultimately need State, not StateFlow.

Comment: If you have just one thing that's not changing, that doesn't have to even be State because you don't need to trigger re-compositions with it. You can just store the list in a property.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I tried it just now and it is indeed possible to use `State` instead of `StateFlow`, I just started learning android, my fault. But like I said before, `flowOf((1..100).toList())` is a solution, I am looking for another solution - directly transform `Flow`

Comment: Are you expecting a flow that goes `listOf(1), listOf(1, 2), listOf(1,2,3)...`?  Or something else?  If you only want the one value, you shouldn't be using a flow in the first place.  It sounds like what you want isn't actually a flow at all.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Yes, Flow is not the best choice in this case. But my question is finding a way to convert directly.

Comment: There isn't a better way than using toList.  If you really wanted, you could use `flow { emit(flow.toList()) }`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Yes, this is an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a better way than using toList. If you really wanted, you could use `flow { emit(flow.toList()) }`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing your flow in your question is just an example and you want to know how to convert any arbitrary flow.

If you're using Compose, what you ultimately need is State, not StateFlow. You can convert a Flow directly to State using [`Flow.collectAsState()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#(kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow).collectAsState(kotlin.Any,kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext)) or [`Flow.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/compose/package-summary#(kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow).collectAsStateWithLifecycle(kotlin.Any,androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle,androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle.State,kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext)). You have to provide some initial value. I'm using `emptyList()` as a sample initial value.

```
val state: State<List<Int> = someFlow.collectAsStateWithLifecycle(emptyList())
```

`collectAsStateWithLifecycle` is preferred to `collectAsState` when on Android to avoid the possibility of using resources to continue collecting while something is off-screen.

If you already have a StateFlow, you can convert it to State using [`StateFlow.collectAsState()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#(kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlow).collectAsState(kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext)) or [`StateFlow.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/compose/package-summary#(kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlow).collectAsStateWithLifecycle(androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner,androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle.State,kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext)), which does not require you to provide an initial value since StateFlow always has a value that it can use as the initial value.

If you want to convert a Flow to StateFlow (which, again, is unnecessary if you're only using it for Compose), you can use [`stateIn`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/state-in.html). This requires a CoroutineScope to run the coroutine that will collect the cold flow and make it hot. It also requires you to specify under what conditions it should start/keep it hot. And it requires an initial value.

```
val stateFlow: StateFlow<List<Int>> = someFlow.stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000L), emptyList())
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, in fact, I already know the content of your answer. What I was looking for was a way to convert Flow directly, but that doesn't seem to exist right now.

Comment: Convert Flow to what? I showed how to directly convert a Flow to State and how to directly convert a Flow to StateFlow.

Comment: `Flow<Int>` to `StateFlow<List<Int>>`.

Comment: `flow { emit(intFlow.toList()) }.stateIn(…)`